# Convert a text file consisting of strings into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to know how to convert a text file consisting of strings into a dictionary. My text file looks like this:

`Donald Trump, 45th US President, 71 years old
Barack Obama, 44th US President, 56 years old
George W. Bush, 43rd US President, 71 years old`

I want to be able to convert that text file into a dictionary being:

`{Donald Trump: 45th US President, 71 years old, Barack Obama: 44th US President, 56 years old, George W. Bush: 43rd US President, 71 years old}`

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

I tried to do it by doing this:

`d = {}
with open('presidents.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        key = line[0]
        value = line[1:]
        d[key] = value`

Comment: Sorry about that, I added some code.

Comment: How does your own code fail?

Comment: @Ken, If one of the below solutions helped, please consider accepting it (green tick on the left), so other users know. Or, of course, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
d = {}

with open("presidents.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v, z = line.strip().split(",")
        d[k.strip()] = v.strip(), z.strip()
f.close()
print(d)
```

The final output looks like this:

`{'Donald Trump': ('45th US President', '71 years old'), 'Barack Obama': ('44th US President', '56 years old'), 'George W. Bush': ('43rd US President', '71 years old')}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=', ', header=None, names=['Name', 'President', 'Age'])

d = df.set_index(['Name'])[['President', 'Age']].T.to_dict(orient='list')

# {'Barack Obama': ['44th US President', '56 years old'],
#  'Donald Trump': ['45th US President', '71 years old'],
#  'George W. Bush': ['43rd US President', '71 years old']}
```